# What does this "of" mean?

Tags: grammar

From [Merriam-Webster's Word of the Day for October 31, *Demogorgon*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/2013/10/31/):

> These days his name is sometimes used in a more generic way **of** something that is bizarre or monstrous.

Is this "of" the same as in "the city of Rome"?

Comment: The sentence you are asking about is just broken.

Comment: Yeah. That'S what  I though. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's either a bad sentence, or there's a word missing. It would read better as:

> These days his name is sometimes used in a more generic way of *describing* something that is bizarre or monstrous.